# Combobox selection based on prior selection

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have my combobox2 display values based on a selection made in my combobox1 so that only data that relates to combobox1 will show in combobox2. For example, if a user selected "Fruit" in combobox1 only "Apples, Oranges..." would display in combobox2 (even though my range of data has fruits, vegetables, breads, etc.) I have modified some code I found so that combobox1 displays values based on my range of data. Can anyone assist with modifying the code further so that combobox2 displays values that relate ONLY to the combobox1 selection. Here is the code I have:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_GotFocus()

Dim wbBook As Workbook
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim rnData As Range

'Variant to conatin the data to be placed in the combo box
Dim vaData As Variant

'Initialize the Excel objects
Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets("Analysis")

'Set the range equal to the data, and then (temporarily) copy the unique values of that data to the L column

With wsSheet
    Set rnData = Range(.Range("B23"), .Range("B100000").End(xlUp))
    rnData.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=.Range("P23"), _
        unique:=True
    'Store the unique values in vaData
    vaData = .Range(.Range("P24"), .Range("P100000").End(xlUp)).Value
    'clean up the contents of the temporary data storage
    .Range(.Range("P23"), .Range("P100000").End(xlUp)).ClearContents
End With

'display the unique values in vaData in the combobox already in existence on the worksheet
With wsSheet.OLEObjects("Combobox1").Object
    .Clear
    .List = vaData
    .ListIndex = -1
End With

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can do this outside of vba, see [here](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dependent-drop-down-lists.html)

Comment: My preference is to do this using VBA because my data set will be continously updated and changing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you don't have to use the Advanced filter to get the unique items for combobox1.
Once you have made a selection from combobox1 then combobox2 will be populated. I am assuming the values are for combobox2 would be in Column C, change the offset if that is not the case.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_GotFocus()
    Dim cUnique As Collection
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim vNum As Variant

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analysis")
    Set rng = sh.Range("B23", sh.Range("B23").End(xlDown))
    Set cUnique = New Collection

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each Cell In rng.Cells
        cUnique.Add Cell.Value, CStr(Cell.Value)
    Next Cell

    On Error GoTo 0
    Me.ComboBox1.Clear

    For Each vNum In cUnique
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem vNum
    Next vNum
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim rws As Long, rng As Range, sh As Worksheet, c As Range
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analysis")

    With sh
        rws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("B23:B" & rws)
    End With
    Me.ComboBox2.Clear
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If c = Me.ComboBox1 Then
            Me.ComboBox2.AddItem c.Offset(, 1)
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Also check here for a similar example.

http://www.xlorate.com/excel-questions.html#Dependent%20ComboBox

Comment: Thank you. I will test this.

Comment: I tested, but Combo box returned no values. Just blank. Any ideas? Thank you.